# How i can set vibration for sms and ringtone for calls in objective c for iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have one problem with my app, I would like to set different options for SMS (whats'app, etc.) and for calls that I receive,  vibration for sms and ringtone for calls, is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to modify system sounds for incoming sms or calls

in fact you cannot generally control anything not inside your app (Extensions are an exception obviously)

Comment: How is the GRingtones app able to do it??